# Why would the computation time be hugely different for the same computation expressed in different but totally equivalent forms?

Tags: plotting, fourier-analysis, code-request

I was trying to plot an interpolation function from fourier data. The plot was very fast and straightforward when I used the following code:

```
sr=500;
dt=1/sr;
nn=40000;
f=Interpolation[Transpose[{Table[(n-1)sr/nn,{n,nn}],Abs[Fourier[Table[{z,uwave[15,.4,z]},{z,0,dt(nn-1),dt}][[All,2]],FourierParameters->{1,1}]]^2];
Plot[f[x],{x,0,5},PlotRange->All]
```

and this is an instant plot. However, when I try to skip assigning the interpolation function to f and instead write:

```
Plot[Interpolation[Transpose[{Table[(n-1)sr/nn,{n,nn}],Abs[Fourier[Table[{z,uwave[15,.4,z]},{z,0,dt(nn-1),dt}][[All,2]],FourierParameters->{1,1}]]^2][x],{x,0,5},PlotRange->All]
```

The kernel fell to a status of not working and eventually crashing. Why is this the case, how should I avoid the problem if I want to collect f[x] at different time t?

Comment: I would guess it's because `Plot` doesn't assume that the internal form can be evaluated once and reused, but `Interpolation` structures are usually meant to be evaluated once and reused. Saving `f` makes this difference explicit for _Mathematica_, so the `Interpolation` is not recalculated for every plot point.

Comment: You should include all the code needed to reproduce your examples. Several values are undefined.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. But this means I will not be able to create a table of function f interpolated at different t (time), which is the reason I am not assigning f and want to use the explicit code instead. Is there a way to fix this? To clarify, for each t, there is an interpolation function f[x,t].

Comment: Also all relevant parameters have been added except for function uwave, which is any function that is ''complicated'' like the solution to some random nonlinear wave equation.

Comment: There are syntax errors in the definition of `f` and in the second `Plot`

Answer (score 4):

The short answer here is that Plot holds the argument unevaluated (because it's expecting an expression with a formal argument that the Plot variable can be substitued for, and if it evaluated the expression it could destroy that "workflow"). So, the expression gets evaluated for every x value substitution.

If you know that your expression can be "safely" evaluated (i.e. you know that the result of forcing evaluation will be an appropriate format for the Plot), then you can just wrap it in Evaluate.

```
Plot[Evaluate[Interpolation[...elided the details...][x]], {x, 0, 5}]
```

Having said that, it's really not at all clear why you can't "pre-define" your interpolation function, even if it's parameterized. If you can describe your plotting function as f[x,t] where t is a parameter, then why can't you define f[t_]:=Interpolation[...stuff dependent on t...]? Then you can evaluate f[someT] whenever you want. You can wrap this in Evaluate within the Plot, or (what I tend to do) wrap the Plot in With and set a local variable to f[someT].